# Deriving ordinary least squares (OLS) in matrix form

Tags: fitting, linear-algebra

How can I instruct *Mathematica* to derive the OLS in matrix form with respect to $\beta$ and obtain the result ${-2X}^{T}(y-X\beta)$?

The matrices have the following dimensions: $y_{n \times 1}$, $X_{n \times k}$, ${\beta}_{k \times 1}$. At some point, *Mathematica* should be aware that ${\beta}^{T}{X}^{T}y={y}^{T}X\beta$ because they represent the same scalar. More details about this topic here: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/OLSDerivation.pdf

I am a beginner in *Mathematica* and I tried the following code without any success:

```
$Assumptions = 
  {Element[y, Matrices[{n, 1}]], 
   Element[X, Matrices[{n, k}]],
   Element[B, Matrices[{k, 1}]]};

D[(Transpose[(y-X.B)]).(y-X.B), {B}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I know its frustrating but mathematica simply has very little capability for dealing with abstract matrices.  An important thing to be aware of, typically only functions that support an `Assumptions` option will make use of `$Assumptions`. `D`, `Dot` and `Transpose` do not so your first statement does nothing here.